# Arduino HC-05 Bluetooth after several connections it crashes

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

So I use a Arduino Nano and a HC-05 Bluetooth module.
The problem is that after several connections made one after another the module stops connecting to the device. 
The android application is not the problem because I try to connect with other applications and same problem.

I did try to add a watch dog on the arduino nano but seem that it does not crash in the loop .
Got any suggestions what I could do ?

Edit: So I've seen if I use watchdog with the original bootloader doesn't work , got other solutions how to reset or why my Bluetooth module does not allow connections after it crashes?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the module and the datasheets?

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/F3O/K70G/H1LWQ0PO/F3OK70GH1LWQ0PO.pdf  and http://www.mcu-turkey.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/HC-Serial-Bluetooth-Products-201104.pdf

Comment: This is the 3V3 device or did you buy the one with the 5V->3V3 converter built in?  Can you provide the link to the module itself?

Comment: the module has a converter I can show you tomorow photo to the module and how I use it . but it has a 5v stabilizator

Comment: the module works fine but If I repeat this : connect - disconnect , connect - disconnect after a few of does it will not let me connect anymore.